# Does Icon of Fear's additional effect still work if no ally is close enough to the target?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

The **Icon of Fear** Cleric power has the following effect:

> One ally adjacent to you can shift up to 2 squares as a free action and must end adjacent to the target.

If none of my allies can get to the targeted enemy in 2 squares, does the effect not work or can they use this shifting thing somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they can't get to the target, they can't shift.

"Must end adjacent to the target" is a conditional that has to be met for the shift to occur. So they can shift 0, 1 or 2 squares, but in order to move at all, the movement must end adjacent to the target.

What is *not* covered is what happens if the shift is interrupted and they can't continue the shift. If it is, then they go back to their starting location as the triggered action renders the whole move invalid.

That said, as webbcode [points out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50768/does-icon-of-fears-additional-effect-still-work-if-no-ally-is-close-enough-to-t/50769?noredirect=1#comment104284_50769) barring an immediate interrupt, or in some cases difficult terrain, since the ally has to be adjacent to you, this restriction should not be a problem.

Comment: This said, barring difficult terrain and a reach weapon or a reach greater than 2, shift 2 should always be enough for your ally to reach the target. Remember here, that the power also specifies that the benefitting ally must be adjacent to you before the shift.